# Why does this try catch statement not work?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autoplay

I am currently making a webpage.

In one function I play an audio item. However Chrome is blocking this if the user hasn't interacted with the page so it gave me the usual error message `play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`. In reaction to that I wanted to catch the error message:

```js
audio = document.getElementById("audio");
try{
  audio.play();
} 
catch(error){
  //I am currently doing nothing
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls>
  <source src="https://dl.last.fm/static/1618838835/126178029/27849967d1ce2a81d9bf47d1e8a9eb69e11a012ae93b6113edddcfb91ab488c6/Death+Grips+-+Guillotine.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Somehow Chrome still shows the error message which I don't understand. Can someone explain to me how this is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.play` method returns a `Promise`, so you can `await` it to catch the error.

```js
audio = document.getElementById("audio");
(async ()=>{
  try{
    await audio.play();
  } catch(e){
    //console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls>
  <source src="https://dl.last.fm/static/1618838835/126178029/27849967d1ce2a81d9bf47d1e8a9eb69e11a012ae93b6113edddcfb91ab488c6/Death+Grips+-+Guillotine.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the `"message": "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first"` error in the console

Comment: @JeremyThille That's because the snippets logs the error.

Comment: But isn't OP's question, how to not log this message? Catch it, then do nothing with it?

Comment: Aaaah I didn't get that you were _explicitely_ logging the error. I thought "the snippet" was doing it (meaning, the way a SO snippet works).